# Primefaces PanelMenu Target on iframe

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use PanelMenu to build menu and the target is an iframe.

What I want to get, when I click menuItem in panelMenu, the result should display in iframe.

What I get, the result display in same windows, like "_self".

I tried use an other menu component, like slideMenu and tieredMenu, it display in target iframe, like what I want.

Is this a bug in panelMenu or may be I use in wrong way?

panelMenu code:

```
<h:form id="menuForm">
    <p:panelMenu id="appSlideMenu" autoDisplay="false" toggleEvent="click" style="width:250px">
        <p:submenu label="Homepage">
            <p:menuitem value="Primefaces" url="http://www.primefaces.org" target="dcontainer" />
        </p:submenu>
    </p:panelMenu>
</h:form>
```

slideMenu code:

```
<h:form id="menuForm">
    <p:slideMenu id="appSlideMenu" autoDisplay="false" toggleEvent="click" style="width:250px">
        <p:submenu label="Homepage">
            <p:menuitem value="Primefaces" url="http://www.primefaces.org" target="dcontainer" />
        </p:submenu>
    </p:slideMenu>
</h:form>
```

iframe code:

```
<h:body>

    <div class="row-container">

        <div class="first-row">
            <div class="start-button">
                <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-arrow-right" value="Start"
                    oncomplete="PF('nsidebar').show()" />
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <ui:include src="bottom.xhtml" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="second-row">
            <iframe id="dcontainer" name="dcontainer"> </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p:sidebar widgetVar="nsidebar" style="width:300px;">
        <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
    </p:sidebar>

</h:body>
```

Please help... Thank you...

Primeface 7.0 Community
Tomcat 9.0.6

Comment: And the error you get in the browser console is? And _blank works?

Comment: I don't get any error in browser or in console. The `_blank` display in the same page, so the same result.

Comment: So target not working is not related to an iframe. Well, that narrows things down and make the problem more general. Did you try disabling ajax in this menu item?

Comment: Yes, already tried, doesn't work. the same result.

Comment: if you already tried, please next time **mention things like this**

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried it base on your idea :)

Comment: I think, it's a bug https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5339

Comment: Sorry, because of the formulation in your comment I thought you tried it before my comment. And yes, it might be a bug, but what is strange in the formulation, it seems to be a client-side (javascript) issue that I expected to fail for other menu's as well.